# How to filter only by year?

Tags: c#, mongodb

I want to find documents that matches to the given year.

I am using MongoDb.Driver, and currently i need a solution with this library.

```cs
int year = 2019;
var filter = Builders<CubesDataMdb>.Filter.Eq(x => x.DateOfCreation.Year, year);
var response = await Collection.Find(filter).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

Exception says: *"Unable to determine the serialization information for x => x.DateOfCreation.Year."*
I expect the output to be one document which year is equal to my variable, no matter what is the other part of the date

Comment: Is `DateOfCreation` a `string` in your database if that is correct then you can't get the `Year` value from a `string date`.

Comment: it is *date* format.

Comment: i have posted a response. Hope it will clear some air why the `DateOfCreatio.Year` was not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to search by range:

```
int year = 2019;
DateTime startDate = new DateTime(year, 1, 1);
DateTime endDate = new DateTime(year + 1, 1, 1);
var filter = Builders<CubesDataMdb>.Filter.Gte(x => x.DateOfCreation, startDate)
            & Builders<CubesDataMdb>.Filter.Lt(x => x.DateOfCreation, endDate);
var response = await Collection.Find(filter).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

So here we're making two dates: `2019/01/01` and `2020/01/01`. Then we can search for all records whose dates are greater or equal to `2091/01/01` and less than `2020/01/01`.

Comment: thats worked for me! i appreciate your help! thanks

Answer (score 1):

As it is already been answered i am just going to provide an alternative approach for future reference(*if anyone needs*).

> First the issue *Unable to determine the serialization information for x => x.DateOfCreation.Year*

The reason why you are getting this error is because the `c#` driver is translating the given linq statement:

```
int year = 2019;
var filter = Builders<CubesDataMdb>.Filter.Eq(x => x.DateOfCreation.Year, year);
var response = await Collection.Find(filter).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

To mongo shell script like:

```
db.Collection.find({"{document}{DateOfCreation}.Year":{$eq:2019}})
```

So, the Mongodb c# driver is not able to map it to any field as the field `{document}{DateOfCreation}.Year` does not exist in the class `CubesDataMdb` or in any of the documents stored in the Database(*ps a simpler explanation would be that `MongoDB` does not support the linq converted syntax of `field.Year`*).

So, an alternative approach apart from the answer provided by [John](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57176018/2417602).

**Aggregation:**

Use a `ViewModel` which have the same properties as the model `CubesDataMdb` apart from an additional property

```
public int Year { get; set; }
```

Then construct a `$addFields` stage to be used in the aggregation pipeline by extracting the year part from the object `DateOfCreation` using `$year` (*by assuming the `DateOfCreation` have mongo dates and not string dates*) as:

```
BsonDocument expressionString = new BsonDocument(new List<BsonElement>() {
    new BsonElement("Year", new BsonDocument(new BsonElement("$year", "$DateOfCreation"))),
});
BsonDocument addFieldsStageMongo = new BsonDocument(new BsonElement("$addFields", expressionMongo));
//adding the stage to the aggrigation pipeline
var response = await Collection
              .Aggregate()
              .AppendStage<BsonDocument>(addFieldsStageMongo)
              .Match(m=>m.Year == year)//using the filter on the newly added field of pipeline
              .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

The mongo shell equivalent query would be:

```
db.Collection.aggregate([
{$addFields:{
    Year:{$year:"$DateOfCreation"}
}},
{
    $match:{
        "Year":2019
    }
}
])
```